# Powershell network command in powershell for linux

Tags: linux, powershell

First of all - I'm not a nerd in Linux..

I'm trying to convert a Power-shell startup script from Windows to a Ubuntu 22.04 Linux box.

And Powershell should be crossplatform - OR?

I'm missing a lot of commands like Get-NetIpAddres, Get-NetAdapter, Get-NetRoute etc. in

Short description of my running Windows powershell:
Import-csv (containing predefined gateway)

Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0

Start-Process "according to result of Gateway".

This works perfect at Windows but I'm stuck in Powershell 7.3.4 for Linux

Please help.

Comment: Read following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/unix-support?force_isolation=true&view=powershell-7.3